# I enabled debugging but I still get the same message: There has been a critical error on your website

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I have changed the config setting to enable debugging as follows;

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
```

When I refresh the page I still get he unhelpful message:

```
There has been a critical error on your website.
```

How can I get it to spilt its guts on the screen and show the actual error?

Comment: Add `define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );` and or `define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );`  and set `WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY` to `false` and then go check your error log which should be generated in `/wp-content/debug.log` assuming it is not being set to output somewhere else by your server settings. Useful reading: https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/

Comment: Is there no way to display the error in the webpage rather than having to open the log file?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Fatal error handling has been introduced in WordPress 5.1 and 5.2. also known as "Screen Of Death (WSOD) protection."
To exclude this "protection" and restore the old way error catching you should add this to your wp-config.php file since  WP_DEBUG true is not enough to disable the WSOD protection :

`define( 'WP_DISABLE_FATAL_ERROR_HANDLER', true );`